# Running asyncio in two different threads to process actions on-the-fly

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to process many actions asynchronously: I would like to send actions to my loop and run them in an `ProcessPoolExecutor` at the same time. I suppose I don't know all the jobs I will be running at the beginning, so I can't define all the jobs and *then* start the event loop.

The only solution I found is to run a main thread which can process the actions, and another thread to do `loop.run_forever`, and this seems to work. However, I didn't see any example of two separate threads running on the same loop in this way. Is there another way to solve this problem, and if what problems could there be with my solution?

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import functools
import time
import threading


executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)


def do_work(eventloop, value):
    future = eventloop.run_in_executor(executor, functools.partial(process_action, value))
    future.add_done_callback(run_job_success)


def process_action(value):
    print("Processing %i" % value)
    time.sleep(1)
    return value


def run_job_success(f):
    print("Success : %s" % f.result())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop_thread = threading.Thread(target=loop.run_forever)
    loop_thread.start()
    while True:
        msg = recv()
        if msg is not None:
            do_work(loop, msg)
```

**EDIT:**
I get the jobs to receive with the `recv` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is a little bit ambiguous - you say you don't know all the jobs you want to run at the beginning of the program. That's fine - but how *do* you find out what jobs you want to run? In any case, your test program above can (and should) be re-written to be single-threaded by using `BaseEventLoop.call_soon` to schedule all the `do_work` calls you want to make before you start the event loop:

```
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import functools
import time

def do_work(eventloop, value):
    future = eventloop.run_in_executor(executor, functools.partial(process_action, value))
    future.add_done_callback(run_job_success)

def process_action(value):
    print("Processing %i" % value)
    time.sleep(1)
    return value

def run_job_success(f):
    print("Success : %s" % f.result())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    for i in range(5):
        loop.call_soon(do_work, loop, i)
    loop.run_forever()
```

Or it could be refactored a little bit further to use coroutines instead of callbacks, which is generally the preferred style when using `asyncio`:

```
import time
import asyncio
import functools
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def do_work(loop, value):
    return loop.run_in_executor(executor, functools.partial(process_action, value))

def process_action(value):
    print("Processing %i" % value)
    time.sleep(1)
    return value

@asyncio.coroutine
def main(loop):
    tasks = [do_work(loop, i) for i in range(5)]
    for fut in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
        result = yield from fut
        print("Success : %s" % result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

This also makes it easier to exit the program once all the work is done, rather than having to use Ctrl+C with `loop.run_forever`.

Your current approach is safe (`loop.run_in_executor` uses `loop.call_soon_threadsafe` under the covers, which is the only way you can safely/correctly schedule work in an event loop from a separate thread), it's just overly-complicated and unnecessary; `asyncio` is designed so that programs using it are single-threaded (except when blocking operations need to be run, which is what `run_in_executor` is there for).

Comment: I could send the jobs to process to the main loop using a message queue. I didn't put it here because it seemed complicated to add the Client/Broker part.

Comment: When you say message queue, are you talking about something like 0MQ or RabbitMQ? If so, I believe both of those have `asyncio`-compatible libraries you could use to consume from a queue without needing a second thread.

Comment: I am using ZeroMQ indeed, I didn't know about the asyncio-compatible library. It is [here](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiozmq) for those who didn't know either. Thanks! :)